# Power BI, DAX--How do I count rows in one table based on values in another table?

Tags: count, powerbi, dax

I have two tables, lets call them Table1 and Table2.  Table1 has a column of unique values, Table2 has a column with the same values but repeated.

What I am trying to accomplish is to calculate the number of times that value appears in Table2 as a new column in Table1.

Comment: I DAX you may not need the calculated column. Just build a measure that counts the table2 column. When that measure is applied to a pivot table or visual that groups by the unique values, you automatically get the count per unique value.

Comment: Thanks teylyn, I need the value for a subsequent calc.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If the tables are related, this is very simple:

```
Number of Table2 rows = COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE(Table2))
```

Here is an example:
[image: Relationship between Table1 and Table2]

Your Table2 contains multiple rows per Table1 key:
[image: Table2]

Then you can add a Calculated Column to Table1 which counts the times each item appears in Table2:
[image: Table1 with the calculated column]

If the tables are not related, you can use `CALCULATE` and `FILTER`:

```
Number of Table2 rows =
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Table2),
    FILTER(
        Table2,
        Table2[Column1] = Table1[Column1]
    )
)
```

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue, but I need to look for the value in the same table/column. Also the value is not quite the same. For example, I have a workflow of 1, but multiple workflows can be created based on that workflow like 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, etc. Basically I need to count how many workflows were created based on each workflow. The workflows are stored in the same table/column. Any help on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JVM, that's not enough information to give you a precise answer. Please post it as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).