# PowerBI (DAX) - Countif Contains Column Value (thousands of rows)

Tags: database, powerbi, dax, m

Relatively new to PBI and need a hand with counting totals of delimited values in a single column. So my source column looks something like:

```
ID    Code

1     abc1|bcd2
2     def2|abc1|ghi3
3     bcd2
```

I've created a new table based on the same query that takes just this column and splits it into individual rows by the pipe delimiter:

```
Individual Codes

abc1
bcd2
def2
ghi3
```

Now I'd like to plot the number of occurences of each individual code in the original code column. I had intended on doing this using a calculated column, but I don't know if that's even the best approach. So having something like:

```
Individual
Codes        Counts

abc1         2   
bcd2         2
def2         1
ghi3         1
```

If it's possible to relate the tables, I'm not sure how. I've tried filter approaches similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187150/power-bi-dax-how-do-i-count-rows-in-one-table-based-on-values-in-another-table) but that's caused crashes. The current source data has maybe 50k rows (with 8k individual codes), but potentially these values could be 10-100x larger so I imagine it's best to avoid something that's creating filters of the source data for each row of the Individual Code table.
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original Data

[image]

Then you can split Your code column into new rows using delimiter

[image]

and then you can group your rows based on Code and count rows as below

[image]

and when you come back to Visualizations you can have your desired output

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!